# Best way to start building a 3D printer of my own

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I've been using a 3D printer - Makerbot Replicator 2, since almost a year now. I'm quite good at operating and solving somewhat difficult problems with it. 
However I'm looking forward to build a 3D printer of my own, during the Summer break of 40 days. 
Where's the best way to look for a start (except for Instructables) and build it in my given time? 
And how should I proceed? 
Also what will be its approximate cost?

PS: I don't know coding but I'm a really proficient designer and a good knowledge of electronics too.

Comment: This question is far, far too broad. You could write an entire book on the subject of printer building. Please do some research on your own, and ask *specific* questions when you run into problems.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to build a new printer from parts, using a existing design, or want to design one from scratch. Probably the first step would be to clearly define what you want to achieve. - Do you want a larger print area? - A delta printer? - CoreXY? - Silent? - Multi-filiment? - Budget? Either way, a good resource would be the RepRap wiki and forums.

Comment: Hi! As pointed out by Tom, your question is very broad in it's current state, for which reason I have to put it *on hold*. If you are new to Stack Exchange, please have a look at our [help], for an introduction to how our site works. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a printer isn't that difficult due to RepRap (meant for rapid prototyping) but there are many factors that decide the price, difficulty, and abilities of a custom build.

Using a Melzi board (a glorified Arduino Mega with motor drivers) helps a great deal and Repetier firmware is built to integrate many different types of hardware so those take a lot out of the engineering part. While you might not have to learn C++ to configure the firmware, it helps a great deal. There are plenty of sites that walk you through everything.

After that, lead screws, GT2 belts, steppers, sensors, extruder, wires and the frame can be found very reliably from dozens of sites online.

Cartesian style printers are much easier to build than delta type printers. There are countless numbers of custom builds that people document and put online. Check out as many as you want and draw ideas and inspiration from what they do. Listen for problems and solutions.

And one of the most important things: there is a difference between cheap and inexpensive. Make sure you understand that. You don't want to burn your house down just to save a few pennies.